# map mouse button to scrolling behaviour

Tags: mouse-scroll, button

I have a trackball with some extra buttons i'd like to use to auto-scroll (relieving strain from repetitive motion of the scrolling finger). I know the `xev` button numbers i want to use and how to map the extra buttons to the scroll wheel buttons. What i have so far is:

```
xinput --set-button-map 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 4 5 12
```

(9 being the trackball's pointer id). This does correctly cause the chosen extra buttons to scroll up and down... by one line at a time. So, really no difference from the scroll wheel behaviour, pretty much what i expected.

What i would like is to have continuous scrolling while buttons 10 and 11 are held in. Similar to the tilt wheel. `xev` shows that the tilt wheel actually registers as repeated press and release events for buttons 6 and 7.

So, my question is, what would be the easiest way to set this up? Button 10 held in emulating repeated press-and-release of button 4, button 11 doing the same for emulating button 5. Perhaps with configurable repeat-delay and repeat-rate?

---

ETA:
One easy solution was just to map buttons 6 and 7 to 5 and 4, respectively. But this is less than ideal, as i then lose horizontal scrolling.

I also discovered that Chrome ignores the `xinput` command altogether! Correct me if i'm wrong, but in order to use xinput2 instead of xinput1, you have to use the `evdev` driver instead of the default `libinput` driver in `Xorg`. I managed this by adding a config file with:

```
Section "InputClass"  
  Identifier      "Evdev Mouse"  
  MatchProduct    "HUGE"  
  Driver          "evdev"  
  Option          "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 5 4 8 9 4 5 12"  
EndSection
```

(alter the `MatchProduct` string to your liking)

Now it works in Chrome, too. But the original question remains: how to map buttons 10 and 11 to *repeated* press-and-releases of 4 and 5?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316441) post I use

scroll.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    xte "key $1"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

and ~/.xbindkeysrc

```
"~/scroll.sh Down"
  b:8
"killall scroll.sh"
  b:8 + Release
"~/scroll.sh Up"
  b:9
"killall scroll.sh"
  b:9 + Release
```

You should probably replace propper buttons b:10 and b:11 instead of mine.

then run

```
killall xbindkeys
xbindkeys
```

**Update**
Recently I use https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys which allows scroll mapping and a lot of other things.
It requires root though.
Sample configuration:

```
# ~/evdevremapkeys.yaml
devices:
- input_name: 'Compx 2.4G Receiver'
  input_phys: 'usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1' # replace with your device
  output_name: remap-mouse
  remappings:
   BTN_EXTRA:
   - code: REL_WHEEL
     type: EV_REL
     value: 1
     repeat: true
     rate: .1
   BTN_SIDE:
   - code: REL_WHEEL
     type: EV_REL
     value: -1
     repeat: true
     rate: .1
```

Run `python3 evdevremapkeys.py -h` to find your device.
Start with `sudo python3 evdevremapkeys.py -f ~/evdevremapkeys.yaml`.